# Blazor WASM Load Data before Render Page

Tags: entity-framework, blazor

I would like to load some Data before I Render my Blazor Application because in depndency to the loaded data I would like to render my app (layout, navbar ...)

Now I want to use the OnInitialised method instead of OnInitialisedAsync and with no async and await keywords.

But now I had a problem to convert the data which I get back from my API.

[image]

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        try
        {   Console.WriteLine("Test1Mainasync");
            LoadCategories();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            jsRuntime.ToastrError(e.Message);
        }
    }

    private void LoadCategories()
    {
        
       
        IEnumerable<CategorieDTO> CategoriesInit1  = new List<CategorieDTO>();
        CategoriesInit1  =  categorieService.GetAllCategories();
        
        SD.Categories = CategoriesInit1.ToList();
        //foreach(var categorie in CategoriesInit){
        //    SD.Categories.Append(categorie);
        //}
        
        Console.WriteLine("Test1Main");


    }
```

Has someone an idea why this converting issues happen?

Comment: Now I want to use the OnInitialised method instead of OnInitialisedAsync???? Why? This is a strange requirement. Do you want your UI to freeze? It is also causing all these issues. A lot of people here can help you make this Async. If your controlling your whole app UI, not just the page/component load the data with a service use that service to notifiy when to update all the screen components.

Comment: Why _"... with no async and await keywords"_  ?  You entered a dead-end street there. Blazor Wasm cannot use `.Result`, Blazor Server shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have this method:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<CategorieDTO>> GetAllCategories()
```

and you should call it this way:

```
private async Task LoadCategories()
{ 
    IEnumerable<CategorieDTO> CategoriesInit1  = new List<CategorieDTO>();
    CategoriesInit1  = await  categorieService.GetAllCategories();
```

and:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    try
    {   Console.WriteLine("Test1Mainasync");
        await LoadCategories();
    }
```

Comment: Yes normally I call it like this, but in this situation I want not render the page until I have reached the data because the main layout in different components and pages depends from the reached data. With the async suggestion the rendering will start paralell, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 1):

> Has someone an idea why this converting issues happen?

In your code `CatagiesInit1` is a `Task`, it's not a `List<CategorieDTO>`.  You only get the `List<CategorieDTO>` when the task completes which you have no control over as you don't `await` the completion of the Task.  In all likelyhood, your sync code will run to completion before that happens.

If your `CategoryService` returns a `Task` then the code that handles it must be async code. You can't escape from the async world back into the sync world without consequencies.  If you want to live in the sync world then all the data  pipeline code also needs to be blocking sync code.

If I understand your comments correctly, you want nothing to render until a certain set of conditions are met.  If so add some standard `Loading...` component code to the page if it's page specific or `App.razor` if it's on initial load, or say `MainLayout` if it's application wide.

Here's a quick an dirty example:

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        @if (Loaded)
        {
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        }
        else
        {
            <div class="m-2 p-5 bg-secondary text-white">
                <h3>Loading.....</h3>
            </div>
        }
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>

@code {
    private bool Loaded; 

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Loaded = false;
        // simulate getting the data first
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        Loaded = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your call to API endpoint return an awaitable task but not the IEnumerable, So you can not assign awaitable task to IEnumerable so this piece of code wont work

```
private void LoadCategories()
    {       
        IEnumerable<CategorieDTO> CategoriesInit1  = new List<CategorieDTO>();
        CategoriesInit1  =  categorieService.GetAllCategories();
}
```

You should have your LoadCategories function like this

```
private async Task LoadCategories()
{ 
    IEnumerable<CategorieDTO> CategoriesInit1  = new List<CategorieDTO>();
    CategoriesInit1  = await categorieService.GetAllCategories();
}
```

API calls should be awaitable, else it will stuck your UI

You can use this solution as well

```
private void LoadCategories()
    {      
       var t = Task.Run(() => categorieService.GetAllCategories()()).GetAwaiter();
        t.OnCompleted(() =>
        {
            CategoriesInit1 = t.GetResult();

            //  you may need to call statehaschanged as well
            StateHasChanged();
        });
}
```

Comment: Yes normally API calls should be awaitable, but with this API call I get informations about my UI design so it is important that the rendering should not start until I have reached the data from API Endpoint.

Comment: I have edited my answer, please try it

Comment: @SurinderSingh - surely this this code is just a more verbose version of await?

Comment: Although not so good method but asker can hook into OnComplete and perform his tasks according to his need.

Comment: @SamuelHurni Did you tried my solution? Its based on your particular use case